# What is the replacement of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api() in magento 2

Tags: api, product-collection, magento-2.1.7

What is the replacement of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api()` in magento 2.

```
        $mc = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api();
        $sku = 'testsku';
        if ($product)
            $productId = $product->getId();

        if ($this->validId($productId))
        {
            if ($product->getTypeId() != $type)
                $productData["type_id"] = $type;

            $product->save();
            $mc->update($productId, $productData); //Save the information in the array.
        }
        else
        {
            $mc->create($type, $setId, $stockCode, $productData);
            $product = $this->product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);            
            $productId = $product->getId();
        }
```